# pass array variable to chart.js options

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I am trying to pass array values to chart.js options but could not make it working, here is the code

```
var salesChartCanvas = $('#salesChart').get(0).getContext('2d');
var salesChart       = new Chart(salesChartCanvas);
alert(report);
var salesChartData = {labels  : ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
datasets: [
  {
    label               : 'Digital Goods',
    fillColor           : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
    strokeColor         : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
    pointColor          : '#3b8bba',
    pointStrokeColor    : 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
    pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
    pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
    data                :  [report]
  }
]
  };
```

Comment: what do you mean by `could not make it working`? what is the error you are getting?

Comment: chart is not working, when I pass values like [1,2,3,4,5,6] it is working while with report variable chart is not rendering

Comment: `[report]`? shouldn't it be `report` without the brackets ?

Answer (score 0):

You have use your `report` variable in a wrong way. `data:[report]` must be `data:report`. Here it is the solution.

```
var salesChartCanvas = $('#salesChart').get(0).getContext('2d');
var salesChart       = new Chart(salesChartCanvas);
alert(report);
var salesChartData = {labels  : ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
datasets: [
  {
    label               : 'Digital Goods',
    fillColor           : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
    strokeColor         : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
    pointColor          : '#3b8bba',
    pointStrokeColor    : 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
    pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
    pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
    data                :  report
  }
]
};
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts, i have tried it before but it didn't work. Although i noticed it is sending all data to one point

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the response,
I have got my result by putting all variables in separate variables, insert them in javascript variable and finally call them in the chart.js code like this

```
 data  :  [g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7]
```